# Is stomach of animal (Ojri) halal or haraam in islam?

Tags: fiqh, food, animals

i need information about that animal stomach. 
Are we allowed to eat foods such as  (stomach) or the brain or testicle’s of a Goat/Sheep?

Comment: If you're just going to copy-paste a question verbatim from a [third party fatwa site](https://www.seekerspath.co.uk/question-bank/miscellaneous/q-id0329-what-is-the-ruling-on-eating-ojri-stomach-and-brains-of-an-animal/), the least you could do is explain what's insufficient with that existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the parts of a halal animal that is properly slaughtered are all permissible, except for its blood which pours out during the slaughtering.

> ... قل لا أجد في ما أوحي إلي محرما على طاعم يطعمه إلا أن يكون ميتة أو دما مسفوحا
>
> Say, I do not find within that which was revealed to me [anything] forbidden to one who would eat it unless it be a dead animal or blood spilled out ...
>
> <sup>— [Quran 6:145](http://quran.com/6/145)</sup>

Some parts are considered *makruh* by some scholars, including the Hanafis, because they are perceived to be filthy:

> ويحل لهم الطيبات ويحرم عليهم الخبائث
>
> makes lawful for them good things, and makes unlawful for them impure things
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:157](http://quran.com/7/157)</sup>

> كره رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم من الشاة الذكر والأنثيين والقبل والغدة والمرارة والمثانة والدم
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ disliked these parts of a goat: the male private part, testicles, the female private part, nodules, gall-bladder, urinary bladder and blood
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Al-Kubra Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/22397#p1)</sup>

Stomach is not explicitly mentioned in these, although some consider it *makruh* as well by analogy with the bladder.

References:

- [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/2697)
- [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://archive.org/stream/FPmfkmfk/mfk05#page/n152/mode/2up)